# Using prototype/scriptaculous to hide the previous row

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous, tablerow

I dont know if this is even possible, but I have a situation where I need to be able to hide the previous table row onload.

Situation:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>    
<tr id="removeabove">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now again I dont know if this is even possible, havent found it so far, but when I put the id `removeabove` in a row, I want the previous row to go poof and be gone (display: none;)

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

When putting the ID on the row, I assume you have a variable pointing to the row's element. If so, you can hide the previous row like this:

```
var prev = myrow.previous();
if (prev) {
    prev.hide();
}
```

(And if you don't, just precede the above with `var myrow = $('removeabove');`) [Element#previous](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#previous-class_method) gives you the previous sibling element in the DOM, or undefined if there isn't one. You can also use a CSS selector with it to only match a previous element matching the selector, but that didn't seem necessary for what you were doing.

If you want the row to *really* be gone (not just hidden), you can use `remove` instead of `hide`, but you specifically mentioned "display: none" which is what `hide` does, so...